# IIS hosting site on MAC OS X shared folder

Tags: iis, mac-osx

I have IIS on a Windows server and I'm trying, for work reasons, to host a site which physical path is shared from a Mac OS X

I've tryied first using my pc : I've shared a folder on my pc, mapped it as physical path in the server IIS, settled up a pair of permissions and worked like a charm

Now I'm trying to do the same from the Mac : I've shared the folder, checked access using server's file explorer and mapped as physical path in IIS
I've changed host file, so when I access www.testsite.pc I open the pc shared folder version and when I go to www.testsite.mac I open the mac one

Given that, a request to www.testsite.mac works : it opens the site's homepage (which is a .NET url rewrited aspx, so it's a non trivial result)

but if I request www.testsite.mac/anything.ext I have a strange error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

The weird is, IIS searches the config file having the page name as a directory:

> Config Error Cannot read configuration file
>
> Config File \?\UNC\IMAC\**testsite\anything.ext\web.config**

when the web.config is, obviously, in \testsite root

This happens both with .html and .aspx files, and even with the robots.txt!

If I copy \IMAC\testsite on a server local folder and change the physical mapping, the site works as expected so I suppose there's something  in the shared folder but I wonder what it could be

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

---

Two updates:

firstly, I was really convinced it could be some kind of file system issue, so I created a ExFAT partition on Mac, copied files, shared and remapped IIS : no luck, the error is always the same both with network and linked path (showed differently in the error message, of course)

secondly, unexisting resources give 404 responses meaning something other than the homepage is working

```
www.testsite.mac/anything.ext --> 503.19

www.testsite.mac/existing.not --> 404
```

---

Third update: it works on my machine

It seems strange, 'cause the server is also the domain hub, but the same process replicated on my workstation gives the expected result (anything.ext opens as a web page)

So, I must suppose there's something obsolete in Windows Server 2008 R2. Going deeper

Comment: If in IIS the inetpub is like in c:\inetpub, can you make a sub directory link (like c:\inetpub\imac), with mklink, so the share access will be transparent to IIS ?

Comment: go into into your inetpub in command prompt, and type something like; mklink /d IMAC \\imac\share

Comment: thanks, sorry I came up with it meanwhile, I was putting an extra \ but I've understood it's a link. unfortunately it does not work either, same error but it changes the path

Comment: You must grant the application pool identity enough permissions on the UNC path so that `web.config` (whether exists or not) can be queried by IIS (as it attempts to load IIS configuration from the file). Generally speaking, don't host files remotely, unless you really know how to configure the folder/files permissions. In your case, I don't see a necessity.

Comment: @LexLi I haven't reported the necessities 'cause they aren't relevant for technical purposes. 

IIS has permission to access the web.config, otherwise it wouldn't either open the homepage : the reason why it does not find it is that it looks in the wrong place, interpreting the page as a directory (that's why I tagged rewrite), but I don't know why it does when files are shared from a Mac

Comment: "it works on my machine", so I assume that's Windows 10? If you want to go deeper, the only option I think is to compare network packets (SMB) in the working/failed cases. Windows Server 2008 R2 does not support the latest SMBv3, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and which might be the cause.

Comment: @LexLi yes it's windows 10, sorry I forgot to mention. thank you for the hint, I didn't know about SMBv3. I'm trying to force the mac to share in SMBv2 but seems hard; I'll investigate further this path anyway, it seems a good suggestion, thank you. I'll refer any update